# How to know if phone app is closed

Tags: android

please explain me how does android call lock screen after closing emergency dialer. I've tried to check every second if emergency call is the top activity if it's not then i just lock device but this didn't do it's job in android 5.0 and higher. So, I need another solution.

My code:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1/100);
    private Thread t = null;
    private Context ctx = null;
    private boolean running = false;
public MyService2() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        running = true;
        ctx = this;
        Log.i("Point","PreRun");
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Point","preloop");
                do {
                    Log.i("Point", "Prechech");
                    if (activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals("com.android.phone") || activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals("com.android.dialer"))
                    {
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Log.i("Point", "Thread interrupted: 'KioskService'");
                        }
                    } else {
                        running=false;
                        Log.i("Task is",activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName());
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                }while (running) ;
            }
        });
        t.start();
        Log.i("Point","Done");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("Point","Service is stopped");
    }  
}
```

And this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.phone.EmergencyDialer.DIAL");
                startActivity(intent);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyActivity.this,MyService2.class);
                startService(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your complete code,so that we can help you out.

Comment: @crazyandroid I've added my code

Comment: Where are you using this service ?@S.Drumble

Comment: @crazyandroid For now it's like this(I've added some code) but actually I want to make a lock screen app, this is just the beginning.

Comment: Please rectify your code @ S.Drumble.You have not called the activity properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch your emergency dialer like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
 intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.phone/.EmergencyDialer"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Moreover please check if you have declared your service properly in manifest.

```
<service
                android:name=".MyService2">
 </service>
```

Comment: Well, my code is fully working what do I want is to show lock screen if emergency dialer not is on the top.